# Jquery Mobile Dialog with Form

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile dialog with a form on it:

```
<form action="send" method="post">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

What I want is that when the form is submitted, I just want to close the dialog or go back to the previous page. How to do it with JQM.

Comment: no, i think the dialog don't have a form.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjust next sample to your solution:

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
        <form>
            <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
              <h3>Please sign in</h3>
              <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" name="user" id="un" value="" placeholder="username" data-theme="a" />

              <label for="pw" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="pass" id="pw" value="" placeholder="password" data-theme="a" />

              <button type="submit" data-theme="b">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```